# How to identify missing rows/columns in a matrix a place a zero in there? (symmetrical mismatch)

Tags: r, matrix

How can I make R able to identify missing rows/columns in a matrix and plug in these rows/columns values equal to 0?

Here below there is a simplified idea, but remember that my 0-matrix is very large and I cannot check which rows/columns are missing.

```
4x4 Matrix
    1   2   3   4
1   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0

3x3 matrix  
    1   2   4
1   1   4   7
2   2   5   8
4   3   6   9

4x4 solution matrix
    1   2   3   4
1   1   4   0   7
2   2   5   0   8
3   0   0   0   0
4   3   6   0   9
```

In the example you may see that the 3x3 matrix misses the third row/column. The nth row missing is the same as the nth column missing (symmetrical mismatch).

Comment: Perhaps `m2[c(1,2,4),c(1,2,4)] <- m1`? More succinctly: `m2[-3,-3] <- m1`.

Comment: Remember that I cannot check (manually) with row/column is missing.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "how to identify missing rows/columns in a matrix"? Does "missing" mean "all values in a row/column are zero"?

Comment: @MatteoTraversini You should at least identify have one row and one column as your reference. Otherwise we may find a solution that works for couple different examples but it won't be prone to errors and bugs as the size of the matrices changes and so many other factors that are involved.

Comment: Added more explanation about which missing row/column is this question generically referred to.

Comment: Please, give me some feedback if you feel such questions should be made more in  general terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a step-by-step generalized version of @r2evans' solution:

Create a zero-matrix of the desired "solution" size

```
m1 <- matrix(0, 4, 4)
```

And, for this example, we need an example matrix of data

```
m2 <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3, dimnames=list(c(1,2,4), c(1,3,4)))
m2
#  1 3 4
#1 1 4 7
#2 2 5 8
#4 3 6 9
```

Use the row and column names to get the positions of where to put the `m2` values

```
location_mat <- cbind(
                  as.numeric(rep(rownames(m2), ncol(m2))), 
                  as.numeric(rep(colnames(m2), each=nrow(m2))) 
                  )
```

And, for clarity, put the values of `m2` into a vector

```
value_vec <- as.vector(m2)
```

Then, "fill in" the zero matrix with the values from `m2` in just the right place based on `m2`'s row and column names (this is where all the magic happens)

```
m1[location_mat] <- value_vec
```

`m1` should now be the desired matrix

```
m1
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    0    4    7
#[2,]    2    0    5    8
#[3,]    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    3    0    6    9
```

Comment: But desired output in OP is the matrix with `[ , 3]` filled with `0`s and `[ , 2]` with `4, 5, 0, 6`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @utubun yes, I changed the example matrix (m2) just to show that there's nothing special about which row or column is "missing".  In other words, my m2 is different from the OP's m2

Comment: Opph, just didn't get it ) Sorry for a false alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Relatively simple solution is just to subset first matrix by set difference between dimension names of first and second, and assign elements of second to corresponding elements of first (as @r2evans proposed in his first comment):

```
first[
  dimnames(first)[[1]] %in% dimnames(second)[[1]], 
  dimnames(first)[[2]] %in% dimnames(second)[[2]]
  ] <- second

# > first
#
#   1 2 3 4
# 1 1 4 0 7
# 2 2 5 0 8
# 3 0 0 0 0
# 4 3 6 0 9
```

Data:

```
first <- structure(
  c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
  .Dim = c(4L, 4L),
  .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4"), 
    c("1", "2", "3", "4")
    )
)

second <- structure(
  1:9,
  .Dim = c(3L, 3L),
  .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "4"), 
    c("1", "2", "4")
    )
  )
```